# Do neurons have a single transmitters vesicle per synapse they have?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neuro-transmitters

Do neurons have a single transmitters vesicle per synapse they have? So when they will be activated, each transmitter vesicle is going to one synapse.

Or is it that neurons release some amount of transmitters using some number of vesicles when they are activated, and then the transmitters are being divided between all of their synapses?